# Is there a way to allow our users to easily find a transaction by it's ID from another website such as Salesforce, Oracle CX?

Tags: button, hyperlink, transactions, salesforce, opayo

It would be fantastic if the following link would allow expired sessions to login and then go to the transaction detail page or if they are already logged in if it could take the user straight to the transaction detail screen

[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06pDe.png)

https://live.sagepay.com/mysagepay/login.msp?returnUrl=/transactiondetail.msp?transactionID=68D131EF-3C83-489F-B235-0763752CBDE5

I have setup a button in Salesforce to automatically append the transaction ID to the end of a URL so that our front-end users can easily view the charge in SagePay however if they are not already logged in then it will redirect to the login screen and then once logged in it does not go to the returnUrl as many websites do after a login.

So long as the URL is sanitised then it should not pose a URL risk. Only allowing relative paths should help but some server side code on SagePays part might need to parse illegitimate requests from trying to redirect elsewhere

[View Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuDYu.png)

Answer (score 0):

Why not have salesforce call the ReportingAPI and then populate a screen with the details returned (which contains all of the info from that screen anyway).

No need for your users to go to MSP at all, then.

The code sample below will return a list of all transactions - I'm sure you could adapt it to use getTransactionDetail:

```java
public class Tools {

    public static void getTransactions() {
        Tools.getTransactionListXML(Tools.executeCommand('getTransactionList',  '<startdate>' + Tools.getLastCheckedTime() +'</startdate><enddate>' + Tools.getEndDate() + '</enddate>'));
    }


    public static String executeCommand(String command, String data) { 

     GlobalData__c gd = new GlobalData__c(); 
       gd = [SELECT Vendor__c, MSPUsername__c, MSPPassword__c, URL__c FROM GlobalData__c LIMIT 1]; 

        String call='<command>' + command +  '</command><vendor>' +  gd.Vendor__c  + '</vendor><user>' + gd.MSPUsername__c + '</user>' + data;
        String HashXML= call + '<password>' + gd.MSPPassword__c + '</password>';       

        Blob bPrehash = Blob.valueOf(HashXML);  
        Blob bsig = Crypto.generateDigest('MD5', bPrehash); 
        String signature = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(bsig); 
        String xml = '<vspaccess>' + call  +  '<signature>' + signature + '</signature>' + '</vspaccess>'  ;            
        Http h = new Http(); 
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(); 
        req.setTimeout(120000);
        req.setBody('XML=' +xml);
        req.setMethod('GET'); 
        req.setHeader('Accept', 'application/xml');
        req.setEndpoint(gd.URL__c );
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req); 
        return res.getBody(); 
    } 

    public static String getLastCheckedTime() {        
 GlobalData__c gd = new GlobalData__c(); 
 gd = [SELECT TransactionListLastChecked__c FROM GlobalData__c LIMIT 1];       
System.debug (gd.TransactionListLastChecked__c);
    return (gd.TransactionListLastChecked__c)  ;  
    }

    public static String getEndDate() {

        //returns day+1 as end date
      DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Now().AddDays(1); 
       String out = myDateTime.formatLong();
         out = out.replace(' GMT', ''); 
        return(out);
    }

    Public static void getTransactionListXML(String xmlfile)   {

       //update last checked time
        Datetime myDateTime = Datetime.now(); 
       String out = myDateTime.formatLong();
         out = out.replace(' GMT', ''); 

       GlobalData__c gd = new GlobalData__c(); 
       gd = [SELECT TransactionListLastChecked__c FROM GlobalData__c LIMIT 1]; 
        gd.TransactionListLastChecked__c = out; 
        update gd;



        DOM.Document xmlDOC = new DOM.Document();
        xmlDOC.load(xmlfile);
        DOM.XMLNode rootElement = xmlDOC.getRootElement();

        Dom.XMLNode vspaccess = xmlDOC.getRootElement();
        String errorcode = vspaccess.getChildElement('errorcode', null).getText();
        System.debug(errorcode);        



        Dom.XMLNode transactionsElement = vspaccess.getChildElement('transactions', null);

        try{
        String totalrows = transactionsElement.getChildElement('totalrows', null).getText();
        System.debug(totalrows); 
        } catch(Exception e) { 
        System.debug('No rows found.'); 
        return;
         } 


        xmlfile = '<transactions>' + xmlfile.substringBetween('</totalrows>','<timestamp>');


        DOM.Document xml2 = new DOM.Document();
        xml2.load(xmlfile);

        String vpstxid='';
        String last4digits = '';
        String cardtype='';
        String amount='';
        String accounttype='';  
        String authprocessor = '';
        String systemused='';
        String transactiontype='';       
        String t3maction='' ;     
        String repeated='';
        String vendordata='';       
        String website='';        
        String addressresult='';     
        String vspauthcode='';
        String result='';
        String vendorTxCode=''; 
        String curr='';       
        String bankauthcode='';         
        String cv2result='';  
        String threedresult='';     
        String postcoderesult='';       
        String cardholder='';       
        String batchid=''; 
        String refunded='';   
        String started=''; 

        for(DOM.XMLNode xmlNodeObj:xml2.getRootElement().getChildElements()){

            for(DOM.XMLNode xmlNodeObjChild:xmlNodeObj.getChildren())
            {

                if(xmlNodeObjChild.getName()=='vpstxid') 
                    vpstxid = xmlNodeObjChild.getText();



                  if(xmlNodeObjChild.getName()=='started')
                    started = xmlNodeObjChild.getText();
                  if(xmlNodeObjChild.getName()=='last4digits')
                    last4digits = xmlNodeObjChild.getText();
                if(xmlNodeObjChild.getName()=='paymentsystem')
                    cardtype = xmlNodeObjChild.getText();
               if(xmlNodeObjChild.getName()=='amount')
                    amount = xmlNodeObjChild.getText();
              if(xmlNodeObjChild.getName()=='accounttype')
                    accounttype = xmlNodeObjChild.getText();
               if(xmlNodeObjChild.getName()=='authprocessor')
                    authprocessor = xmlNodeObjChild.getText();
                if(xmlNodeObjChild.getName()=='transactiontype')
                    transactiontype = xmlNodeObjChild.getText();    
                if(xmlNodeObjChild.getName()=='systemused')
                    systemused = xmlNodeObjChild.getText();      
                if(xmlNodeObjChild.getName()=='t3maction')
                    t3maction = xmlNodeObjChild.getText();   
                if(xmlNodeObjChild.getName()=='repeated')
                    repeated = xmlNodeObjChild.getText();   
                if(xmlNodeObjChild.getName()=='vendordata')
                    vendordata = xmlNodeObjChild.getText();          
                if(xmlNodeObjChild.getName()=='website')
                    website = xmlNodeObjChild.getText();      
                if(xmlNodeObjChild.getName()=='addressresult')
                    addressresult = xmlNodeObjChild.getText();                 
                if(xmlNodeObjChild.getName()=='vspauthcode')
                    vspauthcode = xmlNodeObjChild.getText();                     
                if(xmlNodeObjChild.getName()=='result')
                    result = xmlNodeObjChild.getText();                    
                if(xmlNodeObjChild.getName()=='vendorTxCode') 
                    vendorTxCode = xmlNodeObjChild.getText();                
                if(xmlNodeObjChild.getName()=='currency')
                    curr = xmlNodeObjChild.getText();
                if(xmlNodeObjChild.getName()=='bankauthcode')
                    bankauthcode = xmlNodeObjChild.getText(); 
                if(xmlNodeObjChild.getName()=='cv2result')  
                    cv2result = xmlNodeObjChild.getText();
                if(xmlNodeObjChild.getName()=='threedresult')
                    threedresult = xmlNodeObjChild.getText();      
                if(xmlNodeObjChild.getName()=='postcoderesult')
                    postcoderesult = xmlNodeObjChild.getText();
                if(xmlNodeObjChild.getName()=='cardholder')
                    cardholder = xmlNodeObjChild.getText();             
                if(xmlNodeObjChild.getName()=='batchid')
                    batchid = xmlNodeObjChild.getText();
                if(xmlNodeObjChild.getName()=='refunded')   
                    refunded = xmlNodeObjChild.getText();

                /*       








*/
            }


            Transactions__c checkTransaction = new Transactions__c ();
            Integer cT = [SELECT COUNT() FROM Transactions__c WHERE TransactionID__c=: vpstxid];    
            System.debug(cT);     

            Transactions__c newTransaction = new Transactions__c ();


            newTransaction.Name = cardholder + ' ' + vendortxcode;
            newTransaction.TransactionID__c = vpstxid;
            newTransaction.Last4Digits__c = last4digits;
             newTransaction.Started__c =  started;
            newTransaction.Card_Type__c =  cardtype;
            newTransaction.Amount__c    =amount;
            newTransaction.AccountType__c= accounttype;
            newTransaction.AuthProcessor__c = authprocessor;
            newTransaction.TransactionType__c = transactiontype;
            newTransaction.SystemUsed__c = systemused;
            newTransaction.T3maction__c=t3maction;
         newTransaction.Repeated__c=repeated;
         newTransaction.VendorData__c=vendordata;
         newTransaction.Website__c=website;
     newTransaction.AddressResult__c=addressresult;
     newTransaction.VSPAuthcode__c=vspauthcode;
         newTransaction.Result__c=result;
    newTransaction.VendorTxCode__c=vendortxcode; 
         newTransaction.Currency__c=curr;    
         newTransaction.BankAuthCode__c=bankauthcode;
               newTransaction.CV2Result__c=cv2result;  
      newTransaction.X3DResult__c=threedresult;
     newTransaction.PostcodeResult__c=postcoderesult;
     newTransaction.CardHolder__c=cardholder;
     newTransaction.BatchID__c=batchid;
     newTransaction.Refunded__c=refunded;   


             if(cT<1)
            insert newTransaction;
            else
             System.debug('Record exists');


        }
    }   
}
```